# Coupling of rotational movement with translational movement - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to model the movement of a swash plate, which wobbles when it rotates at a certain rotational speed. And a piston moves upwards and downwards according to the movement of the swash plate. Could you give me an idea on how  to model rotational speed and wobbling of swash plate and couple it to upward and downward movement of piston in modelica? You can see the animation of the system that I want to model via [this link](https://s1.kaercher-media.com/media/image/file/48788/d3/hochdruckreiniger.gif)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.IdealGearR2T or Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Loops.Engine1a. Did you have a look at them?

Comment: No, I didnt look at them

Comment: It seems that I have to give as an input just "ratio" in IdealGearR2T. I know the rpm of the swash plate. Piston moves upward and downward when swash plate rotates around itself one time. Do you know how to calculate ratio?

Comment: By the way, the model, that you suggested, transforms rotational movement to translational movement in one direction. I want to model upward- and downward movement of the piston. This movement should correspond to sinus function. Therefore, the model that you suggested is not suitable for my case.

Comment: I think both models work with translation in both directions.

Besides that: Do you have a graphical representation of what you want to model? It is pretty hard to understand the use-case from the description (at least for me).

Comment: I added the animation in my edited question. Movement of components with number 4 and 6 is the subject of this question.

Comment: Understood, so the components I suggested are actually not useful. I think you need to build something from Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody parts for this...